# Оптимизация моего кода

Tags: python, оптимизация, прогрессия

У меня есть задание на python:

> (*) Необходимо из списка чисел путем вычеркивания некоторых чисел, не
> меняя порядка остальных, составить максимально длинный новый список
> чисел, образующих арифметическую прогрессию. Будем считать, что два
> любых числа (или одно для списка из одного элемента) всегда образуют
> такую прогрессию. Если можно составить несколько таких списков
> одинаковой максимальной длины, разрешается составить любой, например:
>
> { 11, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 7, 1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 8, 7, 1, 3, 2 } → { 3, 5, 7, 9
> }
>
> или { 2, 4, 6, 8 }
>
> или { 5, 4, 3, 2 }

проблема в том что мой код слишком тяжелый, с тем же массивом { 11, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 7, 1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 8, 7, 1, 3, 2 } компьютер не выдерживает, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно ускорить его работу, чтобы он работал  нормально не только с маленькими массивами

```
def read_numbers_from_file(filename):
try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        numbers_str = file.read()
        numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers_str.split()]
        return numbers
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"Файл '{filename}' не найден.")
    return []


def solution(arr):
    max_progression = []
    arr_set = set(arr)


progressions = {}
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
        progression = [arr[i], arr[j]]
        diff = arr[j] - arr[i]
        next_term = arr[j] + diff
        length = 2

        while next_term in arr_set:
            progression.append(next_term)
            next_term += diff
            length += 1

     
        if length > progressions.get(tuple(progression), 0):
            progressions[tuple(progression)] = length
            if length > len(max_progression):
                max_progression = progression

return max_progression


numbers = read_numbers_from_file('input.txt')
print("Числа из файла:", numbers)

res = solution(numbers)
print("Максимально длинная арифметическая прогрессия:", res)
```

Comment: Ошибка: `[3, 1, 2]` -> `[3, 2, 1]`. А оптимизировать ошибочные программы бесполезно.

Comment: Есть несложный алгоритм за куб. Чуствую что можно быстрее, но пока не придумал как. Интересная задача.

Comment: а что за алгоритм за куб?

Comment: Зачем нужен словарь `progressions`?

Comment: `[1, 1]` повисает.

Comment: по сути он никак не используется, забыл удалить, сначала хотел хранить в нем информацию о прогрессиях и их длине

Comment: пробовал решить через формулу n-го члена прогрессии, но работу программы это не улучшило

Comment: Не нужно формул. Нужно разобраться с повисанием на равных элементах и с ошибкой, когда не соблюдается порядок. Причина у них одна и та же.

Comment: Нашёл алгоритм за квадрат с небольшим хвостиком.

Comment: программа на равных числах виснет из-за set как я понимаю

Comment: Оптимизация возможно только для правильных программ. Исправьте ошибки и поместите работающий код в вопрос.

Comment: изменил код, теперь все работает, добавил в ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел решение похожей задачи на js,переделал на python,теперь выглядит как то так

```
def search(a):
    # Если в последовательности всего один элемент, он и будет прогрессией
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a

    max_progression = []

    for start in range(len(a)):
        for i in range(start + 1, len(a)):
            step = a[i] - a[start]
            progression = [a[start], a[i]]

            for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
                if a[j] - step == progression[-1]:
                    progression.append(a[j])

            if len(progression) > len(max_progression):
                max_progression = progression

    return max_progression


def read_numbers_from_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            numbers_str = file.read()
            numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers_str.split()]
            return numbers
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Файл '{filename}' не найден.")
        return []


def write_progression_to_file(filename, progression):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write(", ".join(map(str, progression)) + "\n")


filename = 'input.txt'
arr1 = read_numbers_from_file(filename)
res1 = search(arr1)

output_filename = 'output.txt'
write_progression_to_file(output_filename, res1)

# Вывод результата в консоль
print("Максимально длинная арифметическая прогрессия:", res1)
```

теперь для { 11, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 7, 1, 4, 6, 9, 8, 8, 7, 1, 3, 2 } выводится верный результат  { 3, 5, 7, 9 }

Answer (score 0):

Оптимизация кубического алгоритма. Я верю но не умею это доказывать что она работает за *O(n<sup>2</sup>·log n)*. Внешний цикл перебирает первые элементы прогрессий. Внутрений цикл хранит прогрессии в словаре вида

`{<следующее значение в прогрессии>: [(<длина прогрессии>, <шаг прогрессии>), ...]}`.

В список со значением попадают все прогрессии, которые ожидают это значение следующим. Очередной элемент из массива разбирает свой список и переносит прогрессии в списки соответствующие следующим значениям.

Множество шагов используется чтобы прогрессии с одинаковым шагом не дублировались. Можно показать что если первый элемент прогрессии фиксирован, то достаточно хранить только одну прогрессию для одного шага.

```
import sys


def max_ap(a):
    n = len(a)
    if n <= 1:
        return a

    max_len = 1
    max_ap = 0, a[0]
    for i, ai in enumerate(a):
        futures = {}
        d_set = set()
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            aj = a[j]
            for m, d in futures.pop(aj, []):
                futures.setdefault(aj + d, []).append((m + 1, d))

            d = aj - ai 
            if d not in d_set:
                d_set.add(d)
                futures.setdefault(aj + d, []).append((2, d))

        m, d = max(
            (md for aps in futures.values() for md in aps),
            default=(1, 0)
        )
        if m > max_len:
            max_len = m
            max_ap = d, ai

    d, a_next = max_ap
    ap = []
    for ai in a:
        if ai == a_next:
            ap.append(ai)
            a_next += d
    return ap


def main():
    a = tuple(int(word) for line in sys.stdin for word in line.split())
    print(*max_ap(a))


main()
```